# What `eventCount` property means in data from Microsoft Store analytics API?

Tags: windows

I am trying to get some info about errors of my desktop app from Microsoft Store analytics API. This is the response that I get from API:

```
{
  "Value": [
    {
      "date": "2021-05-27",
      "applicationId": "myid",
      "applicationName": "myapp",
      "failureName": "MOAPPLICATION_HANG_cfffffff_0EB8BD08.myapp!HANG_QUIESCE",
      "eventType": "hang",
      "deviceCount": 1423.0,
      "eventCount": 1244.41342561402
    },
    {
      "date": "2021-05-25",
      "applicationId": "myid",
      "applicationName": "myapp",
      "failureName": "MOAPPLICATION_HANG_cfffffff_0EB8BD08.myapp!HANG_QUIESCE",
      "eventType": "hang",
      "deviceCount": 1468.0,
      "eventCount": 1242.87238240919
    },
    {
      "date": "2021-05-26",
      "applicationId": "myid",
      "applicationName": "myapp",
      "failureName": "MOAPPLICATION_HANG_cfffffff_0EB8BD08.myapp!HANG_QUIESCE",
      "eventType": "hang",
      "deviceCount": 1480.0,
      "eventCount": 1297.92338878456
    }
  ],
  "TotalCount": 3
}
```

Among other things, I want to know how many errors of each type were in specified period. I hoped that field `eventCount` would represent this info but as I can see it's not an integer in my case. Also in Microsoft docs I can see the same thing in [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/monetize/get-desktop-application-error-reporting-data#response-example).

I got two questions:

1. Which metric `eventCount` field represents?
2. How can I get number of errors using this API?

Comment: Well, the API link you post works for Desktop apps but not UWP apps. Please try to use this API [Get error reporting data for your app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/monetize/get-error-reporting-data) instead.

Comment: Based on the description of the `eventCount`, it says "The number of events that are attributed to this error for the specified aggregation level." I'd suggest you check this number and check the store health report as well.

Comment: My mistake, I have desktop app and link is correct, but my description was not :)

Comment: So what's the number in the health report in the Dev center? It should be more readable.